# Expiration of refresh token in SPA application in AD B2C

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas#security-implications-of-refresh-tokens-in-the-browser) single-page applications using the authorization code flow with PKCE always have a refresh token lifetime of 24 hours.

I have the same scenario but I wonder **if it is possible to set that refresh token expiration time on shorten than 24hours** time **or** event do not use it and **force user to type login and password every time** access token expires?

Answer (score 0):

Currently its fixed at 24 hours.

You could switch to implicit flow here to achieve this.